# TKinter tagging indexes in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Can you please tell me if it is possible to somehow pass a list of indexes to the .tag_add method so that it tags different words in the text?

I collect a list of indexes of words I need using a separate function. The result is the following:

```
indexes = (('1.13', '1.22'), ('1.36', '1.51'), ('1.58', '1.69'))
```

Then I use the following code

```
    text_area.tag_config('unknown_word', background="black", foreground="#80ff80")
    for start, end in indexes:
        text_area.tag_add("unknown_word", start, end)
```

However, it returns None. It is quite strange, but some time ago this code worked and words were highlighted, but then it stopped working as the amount of code in the file increased.

I'm using Python 3.11-4 and Linux operating system.

Comment: Please create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your code works fine as long as it is called after inserting text into the text widget.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please tell me if it is possible to somehow pass a list of indexes to the .tag_add method so that it tags different words in the text?

You can pass multiple indexes to `tag_add`, they just can't be nestled inside a tuple. You can use [intertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten the list of indexes, and the `*` to expand them before passing them to `tag_add`.

```
...
import itertools
...
text.tag_add("unknown_word", *itertools.chain(*indexes))
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
text.tag_add("unknown_word", 1.13, 1.22, 1.36, 1.51, 1.58, 1.69)
```